# Getting data async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I need to handle concurrent requests by waiting for the result of an already running operation. Is this code safe or does it contain bugs?

```
private readonly object _gettingDataTaskLock = new object();
private Task<Data> _gettingDataTask;

public virtual Data GetData()
{
    Task<Data> inProgressDataTask = null;

    lock (_gettingDataTaskLock)
    {
        if (_gettingDataTask == null)
        {
            _gettingDataTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetDataInternal());
            _gettingDataTask.ContinueWith((task) =>
            {
                lock (_gettingDataTaskLock)
                {
                    _gettingDataTask = null;
                }
             },
             TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
         }

         inProgressDataTask = _gettingDataTask;
     }  

     try
     {
         return inProgressDataTask.Result;
     }
     catch (AggregateException ex)
     {
         _logger.ErrorException(ex, "An error occurs during getting full data");
         throw ex.InnerException;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe, but can be refactored using .NET built-in `Lazy<T>` class.

There can be several solutions depending on whether results of the `GetDataInternal` execution can be cached.

Simplest solution is when you can cache the results of the `GetDataInternal` execution for the lifetime of your parent object. In this case the code can be as simple as (move `_lazyData` initialization to constructor if `GetDataInternal` is not static):

```
private readonly Lazy<Data> _lazyData = new Lazy<Data>(GetDataInternal);

public virtual Data GetData()
{
    return _lazyData.Value; //skipped the logging of the error here as it doesn't add value
}
```

If you cannot use the cached results (your current logic), then the implementation can look like this:

```
private Lazy<Data> _lazyData = new Lazy<Data>(GetDataInternal);

public virtual Data GetData()
{
    var lazyData = _lazyData;

    try
    {
        return lazyData.Value;
    }
    finally
    {
        //one of the threads waiting for result will replace the _lazyData with new lazy instance as soon as the Data is calculated or exception is thrown
        Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _lazyData, new Lazy<Data>(GetDataInternal), lazyData);
    }
}
```